# Creating animation path

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have just been told to change my drag and drop game to be more suitable for younger children.

With this in mind I have decided to click on the draggables, which will trigger them to animate to the desired position (".drop-box.spellword").

How would you make a click event like this..

```
    $(".drag").click(function() {
    $(".drag").animate({"left": "+=-200px"}, "slow");
});
```

animate into an area called **".drop-box.spellword"**rather than animate "left: 200px".

Here are the styles for ".drag"...

```
.squares .box-style {       

background: #176BC9;
color: white;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 35pt;
text-align: center;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
border: 1pt solid white;  
cursor: move;
opacity: 1;
line-height: 56px;

}
.drag {

display:block;
height:61px;
line-height:25px;
width:61px;
text-align: center;
background:#ddd;    
float:left;  
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s ease-in;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should rephrase this question so it better explains your current setup and circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to give you a correct answer because the approach is dependent on your styles for the various objects. Perhaps something like this might work:

```
$('#a').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var targetPos  = $('.drop-box.spellword').offset();
    var currentPos = $(this).offset();

    $(this).css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'top' : currentPos.top,
        'left': currentPos.left
    });

    $(this).animate({
        top  : targetPos.top,
        left : targetPos.left
    }, 'fast');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Animate the first letter to the position of a container, and the second letter to a position relative to the previous.

```
.animate({
    top: $('.drop-box.spellword').offset().top,
    left: $('.drop-box.spellword').offset().left
 })
```

Comment: @sMilbz: Yes, there were some problems with that layout. Since `.squares` is absolutely positioned, it is also the offset parent, which means animating to `left: 0` animates to the left corner *of that element*, so you can't compare the values from your `.drop-box` that has another offset parent. I made a modified solution that appends the letter to the table instead, before moving. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tD9Gw/)

Comment: Thanks David. Do you know if there is an equivilent of the clone:helper with drag and drop for path animation? @David Hedlund